# List the name of the employee whose salary is below the company average but the total working hours of project is over 100

Tags: sql, oracle11g

So I'm trying to figure this question out my professor gave me and I cannot seem to get the code right no matter what I try. The employee table has the employee information, like salary, while the workon table has the information about the hours for the project The code I have now is 
`select e.name
from employee e, workon w
where e.empid = w.empid
and e.name in
(select name
from employee
having salary < avg (salary)
and empid in
(select empid
from workon 
having sum (hours) > 100))
group by e.name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
select
  e.name
from
  employee e
  inner join workon wo on e.employee = wo.employee
where
  e.salary < (select avg(salary) from employee)
  and sum(wo.hours) > 100
group by
  e.name;
```

Comment: Also a problem, since hours is not in the employee table

Comment: Code worked, but I didn't get the answer I was looking for. Some of the people I got in the answer had not actually worked on any projects

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT name FROM employee WHERE salary < (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM employee) having sum(hours) > 100 GROUP BY name;
```